# Is there a notion of octonionic structure on a Lie algebra? In the same way as there is one for complex and quaternionic

Tags: lie-algebras, non-associative-algebras

Is there a notion of octonionic structure on a Lie group? In the same way as there is one for complex and quaternionic

Comment: The most sensible analogue, at least until someone mentions a better one, would be a $G_2$-structure, since $G_2 = Aut(\mathbb{O})$, as a normed division algebra.

Comment: What's called "octonionic plane" is rather related to $F_4$, isn't it?

Comment: $\mathbb{OP}^2 = F_4/Spin(9)$, see eg http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/node15.html#F4

Comment: The octonionic plane has isometry group $F_4$, but collineation group $E_6$. I am not sure that these facts are relevant to the question.